# Does the upcoming film with Venom take place in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: spider-man-homecoming, venom, marvel-cinematic-universe

*Venom* is an upcoming Sony film. Sony's last Spider-man film (*Spider-man: Homecoming*) also exists in the same universe as Marvel/Disney films called *Marvel Cinematic Universe*. But there is no clear answer I can find about the *Venom* film though. Does it also take place in the *Marvel Cinematic Universe*? Is there any official words on it? Not looking for speculations.

Comment: Totally out of context but there was once a very cool fan theory that the movie Life is actually a secret prequel to Venom. That made lots of sense with regards to the former's ending and the fact that both movies share a screenwriter. But Sony made an official that there is no such thing. Sad.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Officially...

## NO

> In March last year, Spider-Man: Homecoming director Jon Watts explicitly said that Venom was “not connected to the Marvel world”. Marvel visionary Kevin Feige gave a similar response three months later, but added an important qualification: “For now, there is no plan for Venom in the MCU. It’s a Sony project.”
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://screenrant.com/venom-movie-mcu-connections/)</sup>

### but...

> Only a few days passed before Homecoming producer Amy Pascal complicated the issue. Pascal left fans thrilled when she described the Sony spinoffs as “adjuncts” to the MCU. She seemed to be describing the same kind of relationship the TV shows have with the main Marvel Studios movies. Marvel’s TV series, like Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. and Daredevil, are set in the wider MCU and frequently contain subtle references to Marvel’s movies, yet their loose relationship with the PG-13 film franchise means they can explore a wider range of narratives, styles, and tones. Pascal’s word “adjunct” describes them perfectly, and she seemed to be suggesting that we’d see a similar approach with Sony’s movies.
>
> Pascal and Feige swiftly retracted the statement, and Feige stressed that “right now, Spidey is in the MCU and it’s just Spidey.” Still, Pascal continued to muddy the water, suggesting that fans may well see a Spider-Man/Venom crossover. “Venom is a character that is closely associated with Spidey,” she observed, “and there may be some day where you see them together, you never know.”
>
> Finally, Pascal closed the issue by making a statement that seemed very similar to her “adjunct” comment.
>
> > “First, there is Spider-Man happily in the place where he’s supposed to be which is in the Marvel Universe. I think everything comes from that. This is the signpost, the tentpole, the signature and… **the other movies that Sony’s going to make, in their relationship to this [MCU] Spider-Man, take place in this world. Although you’re not going to see them in the Marvel Universe, it’s in the same reality.**”
>
> Significantly, this time round Feige supported Pascal by declaring she had given “the perfect answer“.

Comment: FWIW _Venom_ has been stated to take place in "Sony's Cinematic Universe" now.

Answer (score -2):

No, because Venom is currently owned by Sony. Spiderman is as well, but that's because marvel made a deal to use their character in the MCU

Comment: Any sources to back this up?